# Clarification of the rules of this part of StackExchange

Tags: support

I'm already part of https://math.stackexchange.com/ clarification regarding the rules of the questions in the part of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ before asking any questions to avoid writing things that go against the community rules.

1. When I ask a question should I put context and show the work I've done before getting to the problem? (I saw some contextless questions being answered)
2. Can I report bugs in the Mathematica program?
3. Can I suggest things to implement in the Mathematica program?
4. Can I write some results that could be useful for series/integral calculations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I report bugs in the Mathematica program?

If you are extremely confident that you've found a bug, you should report it to WRI. If you are just suspicious about some behavior, you can ask about it here, but don't assume it's a bug and don't use the bug tag pre-maturely. The community will probably come to a determination.

> Can I suggest things to implement in the Mathematica program?

I personally would not find that to be a productive contribution to this site. And I doubt that it'd be effective in influencing WRI.

> Can I write some results that could be useful for series/integral calculations?

If your interest is primarily mathematical, then that is probably better for the math SE. If your contribution would help specifically with how to use Mathematica more effectively for specific problems, and it's something not easily discovered in documentation, then I think that would be fine. I'd suggest you use plenty of helpful keywords so that your contribution will actually be found by anyone struggling with the same issues. You could even frame it as a question and provide your own answer. Sometimes interesting non-question contributions are appropriate for https://community.wolfram.com/.

> When I ask a question should I put context and show the work I've done before getting to the problem?

It might seem like the obvious answer is "yes", but some people will paste a wall of code as "context" and then ask what amounts to a trivial question (although, to be fair, they might not realize it's trivial) about one small part of that code.

My suggestion is put yourself in the shoes of your audience. People are voluntarily contributing their time, expertise, and effort on this site. Very few of us are willing to debug a 500-lines-of-code example just for the thrill of it. Consider finding just one specific problem that's blocking you and pare your first question down to that. You can then proceed to the next blocking issue that remains after the first gets fixed. Some explanatory text is helpful, but don't write a tome. If I need to scroll to find the question, I'm probably skipping it. One of the most helpful things you can do is provide expected output. Often what one person thinks is a clear and definitive description of behavior turns out to be unintelligible to another. You may need more than one example to adequately explain the expected behavior. Consider edge cases, because that's often where the ambiguity is.

So, a template might be:

**Title:** How do I <pithy question with well-chosen, search-friendly, semantically dense words>?

**Introductory context/explanation:** A short description of your objective can be helpful, but if your code can't do most of the "talking" itself, then you probably haven't prepared your question sufficiently yet.

**Code Input** One liners are best. Setting up some variables/functions for clarity is good. Avoid long sequences of calculations that depend on one another, because we don't know where to start looking for the problem. Get rid of all irrelevant options/styles. Simplify expressions as much as possible--if any polynomial will do, use `x^2 + 3x + 5` instead of `(longvariablename/167)^5 + 9999*longvariablename^3 - 17.555*longvariablename^2 + Sqrt[GoldenRatio]`.

**Actual Output** Even though we can presumably execute your input to get the output, there may be issues related to version or session state that will be hidden if you don't provide the actual output.

**Expected Output** An actual wolfram language expression. Create it by hand if you must. We'll copy-paste this into our own notebooks and use it to check correctness of the solutions we offer. Or we can indicate specific deviations. I cannot stress enough how helpful concrete expected outputs can be.

<Repeat Code/Actual/Expected as many times as necessary to clearly demonstrate the problem>

**Things you've tried** You really should put in effort yourself before coming to this site. And also, seeing these struggles can help us understand where your understanding of the language might have gone awry and will help us add explanation to our proposed solutions.

**Constraints/other info** It's very frustrating to offer a solution that satisfies the expected output, but that is rejected because the user has a very old version or was trying to be nice by over-simplifying the question or whatever. Don't move the goalposts and don't expect us to beg you for requirements.